# Open another page (not web) on C#

Tags: c#, file

I'm creating a native C# application and I need to do a simple thing:
Once the user clicks some certain button, another .cs file is opened (with its own design, code and stuff). If it is possible, I would like to know how to close the current form at the same time.

EDIT: what I exactly need:

```
 namespace Mokesciai
    {
        public partial class Mokesciai : Form
        {
            public Mokesciai()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //write code here to open another page called "NewPage.cs" with its own subfiles "NewPage.Designer.cs" and
            //"NewPage.resx", as shown in the solution explorer
        }
    }
    }
```

The application is C# Windows application

EDIT2: what I want in the graphical way: http://sdrv.ms/JXKVEL
By clicking "Click me" I want to open the new form

Comment: Page? Do you mean "form"? As in WinForms?

Comment: Metro? WinForms? WPF? Silverlight? ASP.Net? MonoTouch?

Comment: yes it s possible but noone can help u with the information u have provided so far. as far as i can imagine, no one here is telepathic.

Comment: @DarthVader Aren't you a dark lord of the Sith?

Comment: @jonnyGold I m your FATHER!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   YourSecondForm objForm=new YourSecondForm();
   objForm.Show();
   this.Close();
}
```

Assuming `YourSecondForm`  is the name of your another form which you want to display on the button click event.

Answer (score 0):

That is a *form*.

You can create a `new` instance of the form class, then call `Show()`.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understand from your question, may be you want to do this. You can use Process.Start() to start any other application from your native app.

```
 using System.Diagnostics;
 string path=@"path to the app"   
 Process.Start(path);
```

OR

Create a new form place a multi line text box, then read the file using StreamReader & fill its result on the text box. For more information on how to use Stream Reader [Check out this](http://www.dotnetperls.com/streamreader) or [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx)

Comment: The other applicatuins have extensions .cs, .Designer.cs and .resx
Trying to call any of those throws file not found exception

Comment: you can start only .exe extensions file from Process.Start()

Comment: instead do this, create a new form place a multi line text box, then read the file using StreamReader & fill its result on the text box.

Comment: Then how do people open like a new pop-up login form from their applicaions? Creating a new form is kinda what I want - a new page overall but by creating it I simply get a blank one - I want to open an existing one.

Comment: sorry i did not get your question, you need to edit it, if you want a good answer, tell us what you want to do ?